# Excel Formula To compare two rows of data.

Tags: excel

I have a big report with all of the company's we handle business for. I have the groups I need to search for in column J and the names of the company's for the data start in column A. I was trying to write a formula like `=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$3483, A2)=1` and run it after I copied the company's after the data. That way I could filter on true and delete the unique entries leaving only the entries that were from those company's.That didn't work because the each company on the report could have more than one line of data which it would count as a duplicate. I couldn't figure out an index or vlookup formula since it requires more information to give me a result. I need a way to search and easily select and delete everything that isn't on the list. Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why aren't you just filtering on the company? Are you stating you only want one line per company?

Comment: elaborate more on this "each company on the report could have more than one line of data"

Comment: It's a report from the company for the change of coverage. Column A is the name of the company. So if more than one person changes coverage or if the same employee changes 2 or more coverage, it will make an entry for every one. For example, Bob Smith changes his medical plan and his dental plan. He will have two rows for each coverage, therefore it will list his company in column A twice.

Comment: @Jeeped I am stating that I need all of the entries from the report if it is from the list of company's I have. All entries with any company's not on my list needs to go.

Comment: So build an array of company names and filter on that.

Comment: Create an array formula using what term exactly? I'm unaware of any way to get index match/ vlookup to work without having another field attached to the name to search by as well(like account number etc.